# Plot specific fixed-effect variable with multiple outcomes using coefplot

Tags: stata, coefplot

I run a regression with a fixed-effect that has multiple outcomes. I want to only plot that fixed-effect variable. I don't like the way coefplot does the ticks and labels. Let me give an example.

```
sysuse auto
reg price i.rep78
coefplot, vertical drop(_cons)
```

Now the x-ticks are `"Repair Record 1978=2", ... "Repair Record 1978=5"`. This is very lengthy. I will only plot this variable, so I would rather have the "Repair Record 1978" elsewhere, either in title or as a legend. The x-ticks I would rather have only `"2", "3", .. "5"`. How could I achieve something like this the easiest using coefplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the coefficients different names with the `rename` option, and to control the look of the graph you can use twoway options documented in `help twoway_options`.

Example:

```
coefplot, vertical drop(_cons) rename(*.rep78 = "") title("Repair Record 1978")
```

The best way to find out about options in `coefplot` would be to type in Stata: `help coefplot`